# CV update - Unable to select and add a book I wrote

Tags: support

In my CV update, I want to add a ebook that I wrote and published in smashwords.com. The book does not appear in the search result for selection and addition.

Are there any specific conditions for a book to be considered for update in my CV in stackoverflow?

The book name is "Dr. Deril's riddles and anagrams". My pen name for this book is "Nila".

Comment: I believe that the book has to be for sale on Amazon.